# Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngbTypeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, typeahead

I get the error "Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngbTypeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input' " when I run my angular project. Looked everywhere but couldn't find a solution.

Here is my html.

```
<div class="kt-section__content">
    <label for="typeahead-basic">Search for a state:</label>
    <input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" />
</div>
```

Here is the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado',
  'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'District Of Columbia', 'Federated States Of Micronesia', 'Florida', 'Georgia',
  'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine',
  'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana',
  'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Islands', 'Virginia',
  'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];

@Component({
  selector: 'kt-grn',
  templateUrl: './grn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grn.component.scss']
})
export class GrnComponent implements OnInit {
  public model: any;

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
        : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
    )

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And here's the code from app.module.ts

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgbModule,
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the NgbTypeaheadModule as well.

```
import { NgbModule, NgbTypeaheadModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgbModule,
        NgbTypeaheadModule
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Edit: this is more to do with how the library requires you to use their library rather than a pure Angular thing. Some libraries will give you everything in one module. UI component modules like Material and NgbBootstrap allow you to import component modules individually, so you can keep the size of the imported javascript down to a minimum.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work. Still get the error.

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your code into a stackblitz, got the error, added the NgbTypeaheadModule, and it was fixed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hbdxa. Can you recreate your problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: I tried to re create the problem, but I couldn't. Let me send you the dependencies.

```       "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
        "@angular/common": "^8.2.13",
        "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.13",
        "@angular/core": "^8.2.13",
        "@angular/forms": "^8.2.13",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.13",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.13",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.13",
        "@angular/router": "^8.2.13",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1", ```

Comment: Figured it out. I didn't have a module.ts for the component. I created a module.ts an then created the component and added the imports to the module.ts of the component. It didn't work when I added the imports to the app.module.ts. I'm using a template, it has something to do with the template I think. The documents are not very clear. Anyway, thank you for trying to help @Kurt Hamilton

Comment: @EtheStudios  how did you create a module.ts for your existing component ?   I ave the same problem. But my problem is that my compnent is pretty big, it has some subcompnent.